# UIAlertView transform is not working on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, transform, uialertview

I have an uialerview that I want to transform to the bottom of the screen.The following code seems to work on iOS 6 but not iOS7. I was wondering if there is some way else to accomplish this.

```
    alert.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(alert.transform, 0.0, -145.0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wont be able to achieve this with the standard `UIAlertView` anymore because Apple have restricted what you can do to controls like the AlertView and ActionSheets in iOS7

It might be worth looking at some [alternatives to `UIAlertView`](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AlertView) instead.